# the default collector for Young gen. of Java 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8？

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm learning the technology of gc of java,reference the article of https://c-guntur.github.io/java-gc when read about the content i marked,the pic
[GENERATIONAL GC - TYPES - HISTORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yVEN.png)

> Parallel Collector
> a.k.a Throughput collector - Java 1.5 onwards, **default collector** Java 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 (* ↓)
> Young gen., **only has the parallel (scavenge) collection**.

> Concurrent Mark-Sweep (CMS) Collector (mostly*) - available Java 1.5 onwards until Java 1.8
> **By default**, Young gen. **uses a serial collection** and Tenured gen. use a CMS collector.

I'm a little confused what is the default collector for Young gen. of Java 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8?
Thanks a lot

Comment: It may not be the easiest read, but you can always refer to the [garbage collection whitepaper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) for more specific questions on how it works. Based on a quick search through the document, you may want to go through the section on generational collection (page 6).

Comment: Hotspot JVM choose GC defaults based on hardware it is running on, so may be more than one "default" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The young generation collector algorithm hasn't really changed much since the early days.

The young generation is divided into three regions: Eden and two survivor spaces.  Eden space is maintained, in effect, as a stack with a pointer.  When an object needs space allocated during instantiation, the current pointer reference is used and the pointer is incremented by the size of the object.  This is pointer bumping and is very fast (actually about 6 instructions and faster than a call to malloc).  The only real change to this was the introduction of thread local allocation buffers (TLABs).  I'm not sure when these were introduced but they were there in JDK 5.  These allocate an area in Eden for each thread to avoid the need for a lock and possible contention during allocation.

When the young generation needs collecting, all live objects are copied to the *to* survivor space, along with any live objects in the *from* survivor space that have not reached the tenuring threshold (at which point they are tenured to the old gen.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help,as Alexey Ragozin said "default" seems not exactly, i find better articles from Oracle cover the detail **1.Java Garbage Collection Basics** https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html#RequiredSoftware **2.Tuning Garbage Collection with the 5.0 Java Virtual Machine** https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tuning-garbage-collection-v50-java-virtual-machine.html#1.1.Introduction-Coutline